# Trying to get one page in nginx to redirect to http and all the others to https

Tags: ssl, nginx, cakephp, websocket, ratchet

I am using CakePHP 2.9 in Ubuntu 16, and nginx, and I have a vps with a ssl certificate installed on it, and I want to use javascript websockets with php ratchet. The problem is that they don't work, out of the box. For example, without changing a certain setting in firefox about:config, I can't use ws websockets in the browser (that's no good, if I want other people to be able to use it). But I also can't get PHP Ratchet to accept wss websockets. So, I'm trying to redirect the page where the websockets are going to run back to http, so I can use regular ws and connect to PHP ratchet.

The problem is, that I can't seem to get my nginx config file to do that smoothly. I have it redirecting on the page I want to use websockets for, but it seems to give a 404 error. This could be an issue with my DNS for the site perhaps, but here is the nginx config I am using:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name server.com;

    location /websocket_path {
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/web/$request_uri/;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /ssl_path/cert_chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /ssl_path/server.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;

    location /web {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/web/app/webroot;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /web/app/webroot/index.php;
    }

    server_name server.com;

    location = / {
        return 301 https://$server_name/web/$request_uri/;
    }

    location /websocket_path {
        return 301 http://$server_name/websocket_path;
    }


    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi.conf;
        #include fastcgi_params;
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location ~ /.sandbox {
    }

    location ~* \.(?:manifest:appcache|htm?|xml|json)$ {
        expires -1;
    }
}
```

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you expect `/websocket_path` to do? Send it to `index.php`? Your first `server` block is missing any directives necessary to do anything useful with the URI, which results in a 404 response.